# android app deployment issue

Tags: java, android, installation

i had an android app and the target for the app i selected is Android 4.0.3 API Level 15.

And by connecting an android phone to my machine i copied the apk file from my machine to the phone.

But the problem is the phone that am using for testing the app is on Android version 2.3.6 installed.

I think thats why when am double click on the apk file to install on device it is showing an error like `There is a problem parsing the package`.

How can it be solved.?

Comment: can you build the project for 2.3 instead of 4?  otherwise, you may not be able to test it on the 2.3 device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest include a minimum SDK version along with your target like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: yes...this will work..but there are some changes in the classes between versions. but i can solve that ...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest you'll have to change the minsdkversion to suit the test phone, or else it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful how you do this as obviously many classes have been added to Android between v2.3.x and 4.x. Not only that but even classes which existed for 2.3.x may have had methods and/or constants added to them.

As others have said, simply set your min and target SDK manifest entries but be aware that if you use any classes only available after v2.3.x, you will get runtime exceptions when trying to test.

In general I can see you running into trouble - if you really need the 4.x API then you will never be able to test on the 2.3.6 device and you will have to use an emulator. If, on the other hand, you will only be using classes available in v2.3.x then there is no point in targeting v4.x at all. In that case simply target v2.3.x instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **minSDK version 2.3**, if you want to run APK in your mopbile.

Answer (score 0):

App is build for Android 4.0.3 API level 15, You must set minSDKVersion in manifest file of the project. By setting minSDKVersion app will run on all later Android OS versions. For example if you set it to 7, app will run on API Level 7 onwards. Not on 3, 4, 5 or 6.